# Ember addPackageToProject or addBowerPackageToProject

Tags: javascript, npm, ember.js

In an Ember app, I wanted to understand how addPackageToProject or addBowerPackageToProject exactly works ?

```
e.g. this.addPackageToProject('moment')
```

I understand this would update the package.json or bower.json of the host/parent app by adding 'moment' as a dependency.
But does it also run npm install or bower install commands after that ?

Comment: Did you try it and check your `node_modules`/`bower_components`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the install command is run automatically if you use `ember install <addon-name>`. In general, the simplest way to figure out the answer to a question like yours is to actually just look at the source code on github.

Inspecting `ember install <addon-name>` we can see that essentially equates to:

```
npm install <addon-name> --save-dev
ember generate <addon-name>
```

The `generate <addon-name>` is going to run the addon's blueprint, which contains the `addPackageToProject`, which ultimately invokes:

```
addPackagesToProject(packages) {
    let task = this.taskFor('npm-install');
    ...//builds packageArray
    return task.run({
      'save-dev': true,
      verbose: false,
      packages: packageArray,
    });
}
```

The `npm-install` will run the install command(but actually first determines if you are using `yarn` or `npm`). So if you are using npm, you'll end up with a command looking like `npm install --save-dev`